# How to calculate CPU usage by user (%us) using Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to calculate CPU usage by %us for a particular instant, but once I run this:

```
top -b -d1 -n1|grep -i "Cpu(s)"
```

I get fair o/p:

> Cpu(s):  0.6%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.9%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si, 0.0%st

But it seems to be repetitive all the time its not getting updated as per top returns. Kindly give me some tips to update this command so that I can get it to get correct result of CPU usage at a particular instant.

Comment: one more command `mpstat 2 | awk '{print $4}'` which is giving me true o/p its continue in manner i only needed for an instat

Comment: why not you used `top -b -d1 -n1|grep -i "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2}'`?

Comment: @Jayesh alerady this one giving same `0.6%us`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
top -b -n2 | grep "Cpu(s)"|tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2 + $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow first result of `top` command is always the same. Second one is correct. Increase `-n` parameter number to get second one, and get last one using `tail`

```
top -bd1n2 | grep Cpu | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: giving same `0.6%us` all the time when execute the same

Comment: Try to call `top -bd1n2 | grep Cpu` is second line always the same? If yes, try `top -bd1n3 | grep Cpu` and so on.